# When imagePickerController only returns UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL

Tags: ios, swift

**Background**

I have an app where the User is prompted to select a media source:  Camera -or- Photo Library.

Once media capture is complete (via Camera option) or media is picked (via Photo Library option), I prepare the selected media for upload to a server (convert to NSData and then a Base64 encoded string).  This works fine ... for the most part.

**Problem**

For certain **video** files (picked from the Photo Library), the `info` Dictionary (passed to `imagePickerController`) does not contain a value for `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`.

==> It does, however, contain a value for `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`.

An example URL from `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` is: `assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=39E4A006-F0DB-4EE7-ACB7-624C9B492271&ext=MOV`

**Question**

Since the end-goal is to convert to an NSData object, encode into a Base64 string, and upload, **what should I do with this `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` string**?  I've tried using the AssetLibrary to get the file, but I was getting errors there.

More conceptually, what causes this difference?  Why do some video files come with one key and not the other?

**Code**

```
let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Select Source", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String, kUTTypeImage as String]
        imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 60.0

        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .Default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) {

                imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

                self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })

        let selectAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .Default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.PhotoLibrary) {

                imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

                self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            print("Cancelled", terminator: "")
        })

        optionMenu.addAction(cameraAction)
        optionMenu.addAction(selectAction)
        optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! String
    if mediaType == "public.image" {

        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        // If the image was captured using the camera, save the image to the User's Photo Library
        if picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
        }

        // Correct rotation and convert to Base64
        self.fileToUpload = image.correctlyOrientedImage().toBase64(UIImage.Quality.Medium)
    }
    else if mediaType == "public.movie" {
        if let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
            let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL)

            if picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera {
                ALAssetsLibrary().writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoURL, completionBlock: nil)
            }

            self.fileToUpload = videoData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        }
        else if let assetPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] {
            // What do I do here???
        }
    }
```

Comment: move self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) to the bottom of your didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo  method

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing, though I still don't understand the difference in behavior.

```
    ....

    else if let assetPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL {
            let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([assetPath], options: nil)
            if let firstAsset = assets.firstObject as? PHAsset {
                PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAssetForVideo(firstAsset, options: nil, resultHandler: {(asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) in
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                        if let asset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                            self.fileToUpload = NSData(contentsOfURL: asset.URL)!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
                            // upload now
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        }
```

Comment: Dan, did you ever find out why this was happening?  I'm only looking for UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL but I had one user hit a case where it was nil for a video.